# Check if an element is present in protractor

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I am new to protractor and want to check if an element is present in a particular page. But when I use isDisplayed() method or isElementPresent() method it returns an Object instead of Boolean,

```
element(by.id('id1')).isPresent().then(async present => {
              if (present) {
                  return true;
              } else {
                  return false;
              }
          });
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here , I m getting the below error.

> AssertionError: expected { Object (flow_, stack_, ...) } to equal
>   true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because protractor API is Async and return a promise which holds the eventual value when the async execution done.

```
var isPresent = element(by.id('id1')).isPresent()
// isPresent is a promise, promise is a javascript object, not a boolean value
// only when the async exection done, the isPresent can be assigned and 
// hold the boolean value inside.
```

// to consume the eventual value of promise, you can use `then()` or use library which understand/respect promise, like `jasmine`, `chai-as-promised`.

Let's use [chai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai) as assertion api to examine the `isPresent`:

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect;

var isPresent = element(by.id('id1')).isPresent();

// because chai don't understand/respect promise, so we can't do as following,
// otherwise will get your error: expected { Object (flow_, stack_, ...) } to equal true
exepct(isPresent).to.equal(true)


// we have to consume the promise in then():
isPresent.then(function(present) { // the `present` here is a boolean value
   expect(present).to.equal(true);
});
```

Alternative way we can use `chai` together with `chai-as-promised` which respent promise, as following:

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised );
expect = chai.expect;

var isPresent = element(by.id('id1')).isPresent();
expect(isPresent).to.eventually.equal(true);
```

**Note:** Only when the `Actual Value`, here is the `isPresent` is promise, you need to add `eventually` into the assertion expression. And no matter `Actual Value` is promise or not, the `Expect Value` can't be a promise.

Another alternative ways is to use `async/await`:

```
var isPresent = await element(by.id('id1')).isPresent();
exepct(isPresent).to.equal(true);
```

Comment: I am using chai expect  ,and after editing my code as

verifyElement(): promise.Promise<any> {
        return browser.driver.findElement(by.id('id1')).isDisplayed().then(async present => {
            expect(present).to.equal(true);
        });
    }


I still get the same error , and I m using typescript ,not javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
const buttonsByClassName = ['tools-menu-button', 'view-ds'];

for (let className of buttonsByClassName) {
  const btn = element(by.className(className));
  const btnIsPresent = await btn.isPresent();
  console.log(`element(by.className(${className}))`, btnIsPresent);
  expect(btnIsPresent).toBeTruthy();
}
```